# Python while loop inconstancy

Tags: python, while-loop

Never seen anything like this. Simple while loop:

```
t_end = 100.0
t_step= 0.1
time = 0

while time<=t_end:
    time+=t_step
    print time
```

Last 3 printed values:

```
...
99.9
100.0
100.1
```

Looks right to me. 
Now, I change t_step to 0.01:

```
t_end = 100.0
t_step= 0.01
time = 0

while time<=t_end:
    time+=t_step
    print time
```

Last 3 printed values:

```
...
99.98
99.99
100.0
```

Question: Why it doesn't go for the final loop when time = t_end =100.0 ?

What is the alternative solution?

Comment: Related: [strange python while loop behavior with comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914663/strange-python-while-loop-behavior-with-comparison?rq=1).

Comment: Many (most, actually?) base 10 numbers with a decimal component cannot be stored exactly in base 2. You are not actually dealing with the numbers .1base10 and .01base10> and thus when you are doing arithmetic with them you can't count on them being entirely accurate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because this 100.0 (result of a sum) can be bigger than 100.0 you write by hand. You should not compare float numbers for equality...

You should read this:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Possible solution:

```
>>> t_end = 100.0
>>> t_step = 0.01
>>> total = int(t_end/t_step)
>>> for x in itertools.accumulate((t_step for i in range(total + 1))):
    print(x)
```

So the last element will be:
100.01000000001426

Comment: How would you do the same task ?

Comment: @user1513100 You can use a for loop and define the number of steps you want.

Comment: @user1513100 I added a solution for your problem

Answer (score 6):

[Floating point round-off error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-off_error). This is what I got for my last three values:

```
99.98000000001424
99.99000000001425
100.00000000001425
```

Answer (score 4):

This is stemming from the inaccuracy of floating point calculations. You are relying on the == operator to compare two floating point values, which is a no-go. What you see as '100.0' might actually be something like '100.000000000314'